# how to recursively change the part of multiple filename?

Tags: python, bash, awk

I have 1000 files with random numbering like

xxxx_0.txt
xxxx_4.txt
xxxx_5.txt
xxxx_7.txt
xxxx_8.txt

Desired output

xxxx_0.txt
xxxx_1.txt
xxxx_2.txt
xxxx_3.txt
xxxx_4.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this...

```
i=0; 
for f in x_*.txt; 
do 
   pre="${f%%_*}"; 
   echo mv "$f" "new/${pre}_${i}.txt"; 
   ((i++)); 
done

mv x_0.txt new/x_0.txt
mv x_3.txt new/x_1.txt
mv x_4.txt new/x_2.txt
mv x_5.txt new/x_3.txt
```

remove `echo`.  Most likely you'll overwrite existing file if you work in the same directory.  So, create a `new` directory and mv the files there under the new indexed names.